# How to compress the js, css files in /public in Rails production mode

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I put bunch of javascript plug-ins and images, css inside my Rails project.

This is the structure.

public/css
public/js
public/images

I added

```
config.assets.compile = true  
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in production.rb

and it compresses fine, if the files are inside /app/assets/

What about the external plug-ins?

What do i have to do to compress whole bunch of libs inside /public??

Comment: Plugin assets should go to `/vendor/assets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Asset Pipeline**

You're missing the point of the [`asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark); specifically the [`precompilation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) process:

> Rails comes bundled with a rake task to compile the asset manifests
>   and other files in the pipeline.
>
> Compiled assets are written to the location specified in
>   config.assets.prefix. By default, this is the /assets directory.
>
> You can call this task on the server during deployment to create
>   compiled versions of your assets directly on the server. See the next
>   section for information on compiling locally.

--

**Precompilation**

Your question can be answered by `precompile your asset` - to do this, you need to be able to store your relative asset files in `app/assets/....`

You can precompile the assets in production using the following command:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will basically compress / minify your various asset files into the different files you allocate to the precompilation process. By default, they all get put into `application.*` (`application.css` / `application.js` etc)

--

**Fix**

To do this, you need to move all your files into the `app/assets/...` folders. This puts them into the `asset pipeline`, which will allow Rails to precompile the assets correctly, sending them to the `/public` folder as required

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking like this

```
config.assets.paths << File.join(Rails.root, '/my/special/path')
```